# Apache serving name-based virtual Host from server hostname (but shouldn't be)

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have an Apache httpd server (2.4.6) running on Centos, serving several Name-based virtual hosts.  The fqdn / hostname of the server should be serving no content, but it redirects to one of the Name-based virtual hosts and I don't understand why, or how to stop it.

In the configs below, a request to http://host.mydomain.org/ is redirected to http://www.customer.co.uk/.

Any ideas as to why, and the right way to stop it appretiated.

My httpd.conf is:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@xxx.org
ServerName host.mydomain.org:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler cgi-script .pl
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on
TraceEnable Off
ServerTokens Prod

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

An example virtual host is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/xxx/customer/docs
    ServerName www.customer.co.uk
    ErrorLog /home/xxx/customer/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /home/xxx/customer/logs/access_log combined
        <Directory /home/xxx/customer/docs>
                AllowOverride None
                Options None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName customer.co.uk
    Redirect permanent / http://www.customer.co.uk/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.customer.mydomain.org
    Redirect permanent / http://www.customer.co.uk/
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks very much
Kevin

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any IPTABLES or /etc/hosts set in your machine for redirecting http://host.mydomain.org/ or it's IP ? Or another chance is it could be forwarding from your proxy server. So make sure it is not forwarding when the httpd server is stopped.

Comment: What are you testing with? Browsers are _supposed_ to store a `Redirect permanent` for an unspecified amount of time, `wget` or `curl` are better for hunting down redirection trouble.

Comment: There are three `<VirtualHost *:80>` tags in your config which is not required. You can write all content inside virtualHost tag as it is in single tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

The first VirtualHost in the configuration file has the highest priority and can be seen as the default or primary server. That means that if a request is received that does not match one of the specified `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` directives, it will be served by this first `<VirtualHost>`.

You can prevent this by adding this (for example) as the first VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```